# How do I zoom out of a specific webpage when using Nightwatch.js?

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I am trying to zoom out of my current webpage (not just the css elements) using Nightwatch. I have been trying to use the .keys() method that is already provided in the framework by using

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, browser.Keys.SUBTRACT])
```

and

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, browser.Keys.SUBTRACT], browser.Keys.NULL)
```

as well as

```
broswer.keys('\ue009', '\ue027')
```

but nothing seems to be zooming out properly. Am I using the correct syntax or is there another way to zoom out using the keys? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, browser.Keys.SUBTRACT], browser.Keys.NULL)
```

try this:

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, "browser.Keys.SUBTRACT", browser.Keys.NULL]);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as well. Doing `browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, "a", browser.Keys.NULL])` seems to work perfectly fine to highlight the entire page, but the zoom does not work
.

Comment: Try also `browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, "\uE027", browser.Keys.NULL]);`

Comment: Looks like that doesn't do anything either :(

Comment: I think it is time to ask the developers. Probably there is an issue with exactly this case. https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues - here you can ask the developers directly.

Comment: It probably is time to do that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution doesn't work for someone, you can do this:

```
browser.execute("document.body.style.zoom='50%'");
```